# Asp.net calling SQL stored procedure that returns MultipleRecordset with heading

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure something like below

```
select 'Result First'
select name, StartTime, EndTime, datediff( MINUTE , StartTime, EndTime) as gap,
Id ,Type from myTable T1
where Id IN (SELECT Id FROM IdTable WHERE StartTime BETWEEN @min and @max)
and  name = 'ResultFirst' 
order by Id desc

select 'Result Second'
select name,min(StartTime) as StartTime,
max(EndTime) as EndTime
from myT2
where (Id = @Id )
group by name

select 'Result Third'
select name,
min(StartTime) as StartTime,
max(EndTime) as CompletedTime,
datediff(mi,min(StartTime),max(EndTime)) as Diff 
from myT3
count(*) Success
where (Id = @Id2)
group by name
```

The SP returns multiple tables-formats with respective heading. I have code in Asp.net MVC that have context for the above db. I tried to create the class manually for matching the above result set (though it looks odd) and try to execute the SP like below

```
var lRDetails = this.context.Database.SqlQuery<MyCustomeClass>("EXEC myResultSetSP @Number", param).ToList();
      foreach (var item in lRDetails)
                {
                   var i = item;
                   Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
```

But i get the only "Result First"  and nothing else. 
I tried the alternate below but the output is same again with only "Result First". I did execute and confirm the SP in SSMS and getting the correct result tables.

```
var cmd = this.context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand(); 
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "myResultSetSP"; 
                               try 
                {

                    this.context.Database.Connection.Open(); 
                    // Run the sproc  
                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    ArrayList rowList = new ArrayList();                   
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                        reader.GetValues(values);
                        rowList.Add(values);
                    }
                     reader.NextResult();
                      } 
                finally 
                {
                    this.context.Database.Connection.Close(); 
                }
```

How to get the multiple result set that either I can loop through or can cast to respective asp.net class which i tried to mapped with the output of SP. I also hope if i can get the design kind of thing for SP to help me to map the datatype correctly in asp.net. 
I also tried the below to get more details

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(reader);
                    int iColCount = dt.Columns.Count;
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
                        {
                            var item = dr[i];
                        }
                    }
```

The iColCount is 1 and item is "Result First" only. I suspect that the custom class I wrote manually MyCustomeClass may not mapping correctly with results-set. Or if the ToList() at end of query execution is ok. 
With data set the issue is only to get the single item "Result First"

```
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1))
                        {

                            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                            da.Fill(dataset);

                            var ds = dataset;
                            foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
                            {
                                foreach (var item in dr.ItemArray)
                                {
                                    string myVar = item.ToString();
                                    Console.WriteLine(myVar);   //here only one loop to get "Result First"                               
                                }

                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Use a `SqlDataAdapter` and `Fill()` a `DataSet`. Each if the `selects` will turn into a `DataTable` within the set.

Comment: You need to a) check the *return* value from `NextResult` and b) having moved the reader to the next result set, loop over it again using `Read` (rinse and repeat for each result set)

Comment: @Lloyd , can you please eloborate the each if the select will turn into a DataTable. I tried the below and get the same result , only one item. code shown in updated question above.

Comment: @Damien_TheUnbeliver, the NextResult gives empty, it didn;t have nextresult.I did the while loop after Read which gives only the heading of first table "Result First" and after the NextResult , the while loop confirms there is no more data. So suspect as provided in question above is if the cast to call query is ok.